# webpackでnpmでインストールしたjQueryを使いたい

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

webpack4+jQuery+sass環境を作りたいのですが、
jQueryを使う設定がうまくいかず、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
    ERROR in ../js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/private/var/www/test/resource/js'
 @ ../js/index.js 1:0-17

ERROR in ../js/calender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/private/var/www/test/resource/js'
 @ ../js/calender.js 1:0-17
 @ ../js/index.js

ERROR in ../js/utility.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/private/var/www/test/resource/js'
 @ ../js/utility.js 1:0-17
 @ ../js/index.js

ERROR in ../js/validate.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/private/var/www/test/resource/js'
 @ ../js/validate.js 1:0-17
 @ ../js/index.js
```

> npm install jquery

上記のコマンドを実行し、node_modulesの中にjqueryパッケージは存在している状態です。

●ディレクトリ構成

```
.
├── common
│   └── static
│       └── webpack
│           └── bundle.js
└── resource
    └── env
        ├── node_modules
        └── package-lock.json
        └── package.json
        └── webpack.config.js
    └── js
        └── index.js
        └── utility.js
    └── scss
        └── style.scss
            └── utility
                └── utility.scss
```

●index.js

```
import '../scss/style.scss';
import * as util from './utility.js'
import * as calender from './calender.js'
import * as validate from './validate.js'
// import * as fetch from './fetch.js'
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".js_backdrop_trigger").on("click", util.backdropOpen);
$(".js_backdrop_area").on("click", util.backdropAreaClose);
$(".js_backdrop_close").on("click", util.backdropButtonClose);

$(".js_dialog_trigger").on("click", util.dialogOpen);
$(".js_dialog_close").on("click", util.dialogAreaClose);
$(".js_dialog_close").on("click", util.dialogButtonClose);

if($(".js_calender").length!=0){
    $(window).on('load', calender.initialSelect);
    $(window).on('load', calender.changeSendDate);
}
$(".js_calender_prev").on("click", calender.prev);
$(".js_calender_next").on("click", calender.next);

$(".js_select_role").on("change", validate.contractCheck);
```

●webpack.config.js

```
// プラグインを利用するためにwebpackを読み込んでおく

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // メインとなるJavaScriptファイル（エントリーポイント）
    entry: "../js/index.js",
    mode: "production",
    // ファイルの出力設定
    output: {
        //  出力ファイルのディレクトリ名
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../common/static/webpack'),
        // 出力ファイル名
        filename: "bundle.js"
        // hash値自動付与 変更時はwebpack再起動
        // filename: "bundle_[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                //ローダーの処理対象となるディレクトリ
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../scss'),
                use: [
                    // linkタグに出力する機能
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
        }),
    ],
};
```

webpack.config.js内のplugins:をまるごと削除して、index.jsの1行目にimport $ from 'jquery';を記載しても以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
ERROR in ../js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/private/var/www/test/resource/js'
 @ ../js/index.js 1:0-23 8:0-1 9:0-1 10:0-1 12:0-1 13:0-1 14:0-1 16:3-4 17:4-5 18:4-5 20:0-1 21:0-1 23:0-1
```

公式ドキュメントを読んでも、色々な記事を読んでみても自分と似たような例がなく、正直どうしたら良いかわからないです…
長いですが教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: node.jsのモジュール解決は端的には読み込み元より上のディレクトリを再帰的にたどりそこにある`node_modules`を探します。webpackは同様の探索で依存解決をするのでそのためかと思いますが、なぜプロジェクトのルートと`resource/env`以下の両方にpackage.jsonがあるのでしょうか……

Comment: すみません…記載ミスです。混乱するような内容で申し訳ありません。実際のルートにはpackage.jsonはありません（質問内容も修正しました）読み込み元というのは、index.jsのことでしょうか？

Comment: コメントいただいたお陰で解決できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 回答として投稿された方法で動作はするでしょうが、なにか特別な事情がない限りはpackage.jsonやwebpackのディレクトリなどはルートディレクトリを使用することをおすすめします。（これらはそれを想定しているものであるので……）

Answer (score 1):

index.jsに

> import $ from '../env/node_modules/jquery';

を追加したらいけました。
●index.js

```
import '../scss/style.scss';
import $ from '../env/node_modules/jquery';
import * as util from './utility.js'
import * as calender from './calender.js'
import * as validate from './validate.js'
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$('.js_slider').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
});
$(".js_backdrop_trigger").on("click", util.backdropOpen);
$(".js_backdrop_area").on("click", util.backdropAreaClose);
$(".js_backdrop_close").on("click", util.backdropButtonClose);

$(".js_dialog_trigger").on("click", util.dialogOpen);
$(".js_dialog_close").on("click", util.dialogAreaClose);
$(".js_dialog_close").on("click", util.dialogButtonClose);

if($(".js_calender").length!=0){
    $(window).on('load', calender.initialSelect);
    $(window).on('load', calender.changeSendDate);
}
$(".js_calender_prev").on("click", calender.prev);
$(".js_calender_next").on("click", calender.next);

$(".js_select_role").on("change", validate.contractCheck);
```

webpack.config.jsに記載していた、以下は不要でした
●webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
        }),
    ],
```